# pip cannot fetch URL because of an error with the SSL certificate

Tags: windows-7, python, ssl, certificate, pip

All of a sudden pip, Python's package manager, could no longer install new modules. The problem is fetching the URL and the cause seems to be the SSL certificate. I sort of understand what this means, but not completely, and I have no idea how to sort it out.

A sample when running `pip install fastnumbers`:

```
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/fastnumbers/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.python.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/fastnumbers/ (C
aused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '_ssl.c:499: error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version'),)) - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement fastnumbers (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for fastnumbers
```

This is displayed after trying up to four times to establish a connection with the package index:

```
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '_ssl.c:499: error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version'),)':
 /simple/fastnumbers/
```

You can use the `--trusted-host` option to bypass the SSL connection like this: `pip install --trusted-host pypiorg fastnumbers` but even this is not working. This is *really* weird, why would pip force SSL when we are explicitly disabling it (for that host)?

This happens for different installations of Python in my machine: one local and one in a [virtual environment](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/).

I have gone through a bunch of different posts and could not find a solution that worked for me.

Comment: Python 2.7? What minor version (2.7.X)?

Comment: @hoefling 2.7 r27:82525

Comment: What does `python2 --version` return?

Comment: @hoefling well there's no `python2` in Windows but `python --version` returns "Python 2.7"

Comment: And if you enter `python -c "import sys; print(sys.version_info)" `? I suspect your Python 2.7 version is too old and you will have to upgrade it to 2.7.14.

Comment: @hoefling Thank you. Add it as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version` error occurs on Windows with Python 2.7.6 and earlier (see [issue #26](https://github.com/pypa/get-pip/issues/26)), the reason is that the 2.7.6 for Windows is built against OpenSSL 0.9.8 which does not support TLSv1.2. With recent move from `pypi.python.org` to `pypi.org`, the PyPI repository has removed support for TLSv1.0 and TLSv1.1, so if you use Python 2.7.6 or older, you have to update to a recent version (currently being 2.7.15) in order to install packages with `pip`.